# MVC4 Register link redirects to login action instead of redirect action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 application that I originally created from the Intranet template, and have modified it to the Internet template, and using the SimpleMembershipProvider.

When I run the app, I get correctly directed to the login view. But if I click Register to add a new user, I am redirected to the login action, not the register action. I put breakpoints in the two Register actions, and they never get hit.

furthermore, when I let fiddler watch what's going on, I see the login action firing multiple times:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
2   302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Register  165 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
3   200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fSecurity%2fRegister    4,152   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
4   302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Content/DashboardSite.css  173 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
5   302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js 174 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
6   302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Images/Site-logo.png   168 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
7   302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Images/Settings.png    167 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
8   302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js    171 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
9   302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js 182 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
10  302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Scripts/jquery.validate.js 174 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
11  302 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js 186 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
12  200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fImages%2fSite-logo.png 4,155   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
13  200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fContent%2fDashboardSite.css    4,160   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584
14  200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fjquery-2.0.3.js  4,158   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584
15  200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fImages%2fSettings.png  4,154   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
16  200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fjquery.validate.js   4,161   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584
17  200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fjquery.validate.unobtrusive.js   4,173   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584           
18  200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fmodernizr-2.5.3.js   4,161   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584
19  200 HTTP    localhost:52281 /Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fjquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js   4,169   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:3584
```

Here is the code in my controller

```
namespace ChargesDashboard.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class SecurityController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Security/Login

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
        //
        // POST: /Security/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Security/LogOff

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Security/Register

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Disassociate

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Disassociate(string provider, string providerUserId)
        {
            string ownerAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.GetUserName(provider, providerUserId);
            ManageMessageId? message = null;

            // Only disassociate the account if the currently logged in user is the owner
            if (ownerAccount == User.Identity.Name)
            {
                // Use a transaction to prevent the user from deleting their last login credential
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
                {
                    bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
                    if (hasLocalAccount || OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name).Count > 1)
                    {
                        OAuthWebSecurity.DeleteAccount(provider, providerUserId);
                        scope.Complete();
                        message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Manage

        public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
                : "";
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Manage

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Manage(LocalPasswordModel model)
        {
            bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasLocalAccount;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasLocalAccount)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                    bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                    try
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                    }

                    if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not have a local password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing
                // OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateAccount(User.Identity.Name, model.NewPassword);
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginConfirmation(RegisterExternalLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            string provider = null;
            string providerUserId = null;

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(model.ExternalLoginData, out provider, out providerUserId))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Insert a new user into the database
                using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                {
                    UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower());
                    // Check if user already exists
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // Insert name into the profile table
                        db.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile { UserName = model.UserName });
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, providerUserId, model.UserName);
                        OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.");
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginsList(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return PartialView("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", OAuthWebSecurity.RegisteredClientData);
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RemoveExternalLogins()
        {
            ICollection<OAuthAccount> accounts = OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name);
            List<ExternalLogin> externalLogins = new List<ExternalLogin>();
            foreach (OAuthAccount account in accounts)
            {
                AuthenticationClientData clientData = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(account.Provider);

                externalLogins.Add(new ExternalLogin
                {
                    Provider = account.Provider,
                    ProviderDisplayName = clientData.DisplayName,
                    ProviderUserId = account.ProviderUserId,
                });
            }

            ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = externalLogins.Count > 1 || OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            return PartialView("_RemoveExternalLoginsPartial", externalLogins);
        }

        #region Helpers
        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId
        {
            ChangePasswordSuccess,
            SetPasswordSuccess,
            RemoveLoginSuccess,
        }

        internal class ExternalLoginResult : ActionResult
        {
            public ExternalLoginResult(string provider, string returnUrl)
            {
                Provider = provider;
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            }

            public string Provider { get; private set; }
            public string ReturnUrl { get; private set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);
            }
        }

        private static string ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus createStatus)
        {
            // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177550 for
            // a full list of status codes.
            switch (createStatus)
            {
                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                    return "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                    return "A user name for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                    return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                    return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                    return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                    return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                    return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                    return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                    return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                default:
                    return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is the code in my Login view:

```
@model ChargesDashboard.Models.LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DashboardLayout.cshtml";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>

<section id="loginForm">
<h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log in Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Security") if you don't have an account.
    </p>
}
</section>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here's my layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Charges Dashboard</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
        Charges Dashboard    
        </div>

    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>
                    &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show your layout code?

Comment: added layout code to the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been caused by two versions of jquery included in the app.

I used Nuget to update jquery to the latest version, then used Nuget to uninstall the latest version and then used Nuget to install 1.7.1. (the version that was originally in the project.

For some reason, the latest version wasn't removed from the scripts folder, and so the bundler put both into the page.

Once I removed the latest version from the scripts folder, the problem went away.

Comment: Solution is simple, don't use nuget for install scripts

Comment: LOL, it may hiccup once in a while, but I have found it very useful!